# How to get format curl request and format to json using python?

Tags: python, json, curl, request

How can I get a response back and in this format in json using python?

```
# Request
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <personal_access_token>" 
\https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/1331
```

Comment: Did you try anything? What happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests
url = 'https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/1331'
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(token)}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with the `requests` module

```
import requests
requests.get('https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/1331',headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer <personal_access_token>'}).json()
```

Comment: Headers need to be passed via the `headers` keyword. If he wants a json response, he needs to end with `.json()`.